# Cisco ASA 5525x can't limit speed?

Tags: cisco-asa, policy-map

There was a need to limit the speed for users on Cisco ASA 5525x but for some reason these commands are simply not available for me:

Example:

```
HQFW(config)# access-list POLICE_TRAFFIC_TO_BRANCH permit ip any 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
HQFW(config)# class-map CM_TRAFFIC_TO_BRANCH
HQFW(config-cmap)# match access-list POLICE_TRAFFIC_TO_BRANCH
HQFW(config)# policy-map LLQ_TRAFFICPOLICE
HQFW(config-pmap)# class CM_TRAFFIC_TO_BRANCH
HQFW(config-pmap-c)# police output 10000000(This Line)
HQFW(config)# service-policy LLQ_TRAFFICPOLICE interface outside
```

But after entering the class, when creating a policy, I do not have the opportunity to enter the word “policy”.

Why?What other options might there be?Thank you in advance!

ASA Version: 9.17(1)
Context Mode: Multiple